# jQuery does not work anymore after re-rendring any RichFaces component

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have a page which contains following components:

- 1 Button
- 1 drop down list using jQuery
- 1 button whose on click event changes a text box value using jQuery
- 2 another buttons shown on hover

If I change the dropdown value, or press a button, then the page is re-rendered by ajax. After that, jQuery does not work anymore. If I refresh the page, then jQuery works fine.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: try to place your jquery code (that I gues is called on page ready or something) into a function and call that function `oncomplete` of your buton (if you use `a4j:commandButton`)

Answer (score 0):

When new elements appear on the page, they don't have the event bindings (e.g. the `$('.menu').click`...) that you had earlier. After you re-render the page, you need to do those again. From the docs:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page.

http://api.jquery.com/on/